# How to use http referrer in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a view in my Angular4 project which is redirected only from my express server. I don't want to allow users to the view other way.

I find a way to do this using HTTP referrer. In JavaScript Http referrer is used like following. How can use it in Angular4?

```
if (document.referrer) {
  var myReferer = document.referrer;
  document.write(myReferer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restrict access via domain or IP address you are better off doing this on the server. This can be achieved with an .htaccess file in Apache or by using ipsecurity in web.config for IIS.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a URL already to which say you are making a GET request. Make sure you have injected the HTTP dependency in the service or the component where you are going to making this GET call. Execute the below code.

```
 this.http.get(url, {search}).subscribe(res => console.log(res.json().headers.Referer));
 //res is the response that you get which has been converted to JSON and then 
 //the referer property can be obtained from the headers
```

refer to this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bMCCtNP4W9Rq0m7IpTZf?p=preview

and the doGet method inside script.ts (existing plunker - forked it to answer your question)

You can verify if you are getting the correct referer by going to the Networks tab in your browser console. Browser Console -> Networks -> select the request -> Headers tab -> Request Headers block